# Fix CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes deprecated method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, ios9, urlencode

Before DOWNVOTING or marking DUPLICATE, bear in mind the code I want to update is an @implement, so other Stackoverflow posts won't help.

I am adapting the code of an old app to update it to iOS9 and 10. I am not so skilled with ObjectiveC and there is a snippet I cannot cleanse of errors.

As far as I can understand, the code "overloads" the NSString class with Url encoding capabilities. However, I cannot get it straight. Here is the code with some comments as description of the problem:

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"
@implementation NSString (OAURLEncodingAdditions)

- (NSString *)encodedURLString {
   //this line raises a "requires a bridge cast" error, when I click on "fix it", another yellow "first deprecated in iOS 9.0" warning appears
   NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                           (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                           NULL,                   // characters to leave unescaped (NULL = all escaped sequences are replaced)
                                                                           CFSTR("?=&+"),          // legal URL characters to be escaped (NULL = all legal characters are replaced)
                                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8); // encoding*/

   /*  this is the closest solution I've got, but it does not work, because I cannot anticipate the value of result
   NSString *result = @"<url>";
   result = [result stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
   */

    return [result autorelease]; //will remove this autorelease because of ARC
}
@end
```

Comment: did you figure out to to fix this issue ?

Comment: @user2924482 Nope, I had to totally evade the problem.